# Why does ActionResult throw error if I don't return a view ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

If condition is true then redirect else return the current view. This is what I am intending to do but I got the first part only not the 2nd such as returning a view, because if I put return to view in else part then ActionResult throws an error because it needs something to return.

```
 public ActionResult Authenticate(Users u)
        {
            if (basicOps.getUsersLogin(u.UserName, u.Password)) 
            {
                RedirectToAction("GetImagesStories", "Stories");

            }

            return View("Authenticate");


        }
```

this way I can't redirect because it always executes the return part but I want it to run only if IF condition fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return `RedirectToAction` action result:

```
    public ActionResult Authenticate(Users u)
    {
        if (basicOps.getUsersLogin(u.UserName, u.Password)) 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetImagesStories", "Stories");
        }

        return View("Authenticate");
    }
```

Comment: HAHA thanks. Microsoft is so funny, why would one need return before RedirectToAction and that without any error. Haha